# Call synchronised on a function in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is there a way I can call synchronised (or something similar) on a block of code. For example (pseudo code),

```
public int getA(int id) {
    if (flag) {
        return synchronized(fetchA(id))
    } else {
        return fetchA(id)
    }
}

public int fetchA(int id) {
    if (map.get(id) == null) {
        p = generate(id)
        map.put(id, p)  
        return map.get(id)
    } else {
        return map.get(id)
    }
}
```

In this case I want the function to take a lock on object *map* if flag is set to true and not take a lock otherwise. I have read that synchronised take locks only on objects. Is there any something else I can use instead of synchronised?

Comment: You can open a sync block `synchronized(this) { fetchA(id); }` if that is what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Synchronising on an Object ist exactly the right thing to do. In your case the shared object is the `map`.

You can do a

```
synchronized(map) {
    return fetchA(id);
}
```

The locking is some sort of contract: if you access `map`, then you'll have to lock it. This can be cumbersome and error prone. Hence the better option is to lock and release within the `fetchA()` method, like

```
public int fetchA(int id) {
    synchronized(map) {
        if (map.get(id) == null) {
            p = generate(id)
            map.put(id, p)  
            return map.get(id)
        } else {
            return map.get(id)
        }
    }
}
```

This way any other method can simply call `fetchA()` without being aware of the need of locking.
An alternative is to declare the function synchronized. That way only a single thread at the time can enter the function.

```
public synchronized int fetchA(int id) { ... }
```

Having said this, be careful with nested locking. That's a good way to produce deadlocks.

Comment: why is the first method that you suggested error prone? `synchronized(map) {
    return fetchA(id);
}` I was actually thinking of using that

Comment: It is easy to forget about the locking. And Java won't do anything to prevent access to the shared data structure if you don't use a lock. So your program will work flawlessly most of the time. And every now and then you'll encounter strange effects. Hence, what I did was correct, but other functions might want to access the ```map``` as well. Especially if that code is added in a later stage of the project by someone else, forgetting about synchronized access is more than easy

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question: just use a `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized (something) {
  return fetchA(id);
}
```

But your approach is not great in the first place. For one thing, there is the [`computeIfAbsent` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) which does exactly what your `fetchA` method does:

```
public int fetchA(int id) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> generate(k));
}
```

For another, it seem that `flag` is going to be a constant for the instance, since it doesn't make sense to access it in a synchronized way only some of the time.

So, choose a `Map` implementation based on the flag in the constructor:

```
if (flag) {
  map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
} else {
  map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and then simply don't worry about whether you need to synchronize in your method:

```
public int getA(int id) {
  return map.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> generate(k));
}
```

Comment: using JAVA7, hence can't use `computeIfAbsent`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ConcurrentHashMap. But it will throw "ConcurrentModificationException" if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.

For block of code level there are four types you can use

```
Instance methods
enter code here
Static methods
Code blocks inside instance methods
Code blocks inside static methods
```

refer this for more info :[Code block level synchronization](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html)